# If I amend my federal tax return before I file my state taxes, what do I do?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, amended-tax-return

I filed my federal taxes a couple of weeks ago, then realized I needed to amend them, so am going to file a 1040X in the next week or two. I have not yet filed my state (Oregon) taxes. I've been using TurboTax. I see two potential ways of doing this:

1. File federal amendment, file original Oregon Form 40, then file Oregon again with whatever the amendment form is.
2. File federal amendment and then file only the updated Oregon Form 40 attaching the updated 1040A.

Do I need to do the more complicated in option 1 or something like it, or is ok to just skip the original state filing as in option 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can go with option 2, but I'm not sure TurboTax supports it. It will probably want to generate an amended form for you.

Comment: Thanks. I e-filed the federal and was going to mail in the state before the amendment. After amending my federal taxes, it gave me an updated state tax form that wasn't amended, so I think I'm ok.